# Angular ng-repeat over complex object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object containing 2 objects.

Each of those objects contain an array with 2 objects:

```
ctrl.mainArray = {
  outsideObject_1: {
    insideArray = [
      insideObject_1: { value1: 'someValue', value2: 'someOtherValue' },
      insideObject_2: { value1: 'someValue', value2: 'someOtherValue' }
    ]
  },
  outsideObject_2: {
    insideArray = [
      insideObject_1: { value1: 'someValue', value2: 'someOtherValue' },
      insideObject_2: { value1: 'someValue', value2: 'someOtherValue' }
    ]
  };
};
```

I want to display the values of `insideObject_x` from my template:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.mainArray track by item.insideArray[$index]>
    <!-- CASE #1 -->
    First value: {{item.insideArray[0].value1}}

    <!-- CASE #2 -->
    First value: {{item.insideArray[$index].value1}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

In `CASE #1` I can print out the FIRST value, from the FIRST OBJECT in each `insideArray`. I want to print `value1` from EACH `insideObject_x`

In `CASE #2` I can print out the FIRST value, from the FIRST OBJECT in ONLY the first `insideArray`.

What am I doing wrong? I should be printing `value1`, 4 different times.

Comment: Your so called arrays are not in valid JS syntax. Is it an object, rather than an array?

Comment: Right - My mistake. The "main container" is an object, not an array. I will fix that syntax error in my question - but still seeking help.

Comment: Can you create a complete working example? jsfiddle/snippet

Comment: Just to make sure : @qqilihq was probably mentioning your incorrect `insideArray`s rather than the `mainArray` (which, aside from being named an array, is a correct object)

Comment: Guessing you meant something like the following for each of your "outsideObjects"?
`{
    insideArray: [
       { value1: 'someValue', value2: 'someOtherValue' },
       { value1: 'someValue', value2: 'someOtherValue' }
    ]
  }`

(You were using an `=` instead of `:` for assigning an attribute within an object definition, and you had a attribute name for an array index both of which are invalid JS)

Comment: Hi @Brian thanks for your response. I tried to structure this code, based on the output from the console inspector. I may have gotten them wrong, from the top level, the console reads: `ctrl.mainArray: > Object {id:1, insideArray: Array[2], anotherValue: "anything"}`

Comment: ...Then `insideArray > 0: Object, > 1: Object` and the values live inside there

Comment: I suggest you create plnkr or atleast change the values to distinct literals instead of some value and then specify what you  want printed/outputted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't understand what exactly you want as output, but assuming you want to print the value of the `value1` property on each object inside of all `insideArray`s, I think you should handle the logic on the script side.

**HTML**

```
<ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">
  <li ng-repeat="value in mainCtrl.values track by $index">
    First value: {{value}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript (Angular)**

```
(() => {
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .controller("mainController", function() {
        let ctrl = this;

        ctrl.mainObj = {
            outsideObject_1: {
                insideArray : [
                    { value1: 'someValue', value2: 'someOtherValue' },
                    { value1: 'someValue', value2: 'someOtherValue' }
                ]
            },
            outsideObject_2: {
                insideArray : [
                    { value1: 'someValue', value2: 'someOtherValue' },
                    { value1: 'someValue', value2: 'someOtherValue' }
                ]
            }
        };

        ctrl.values = [];

        for (let obj in ctrl.mainObj) {
            for(let val of ctrl.mainObj[obj].insideArray) {
                ctrl['values'].push(val.value1);
            }
        }
});
})();
```

**CodePen:** http://codepen.io/cod3rguy/pen/ggbMKz?editors=1010

---

If you want all the property values (`value1`, `value2`, etc.) on the objects in `insideArray`s, you can slighty modify the logic that is populating the `values` array in the above code as such:-

```
for (let obj in ctrl.mainObj) {
    for(let val of ctrl.mainObj[obj].insideArray) {
        for (let v in val) {
            ctrl['values'].push(val[v]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I do this without ES6? I'm not able to use it in my project. Specifically the line that says `for...of` how can I "downgrade" that to the ES5 equivalent?

Comment: @bruh Well, you could use `forEach()` instead of `for...of`. I have added the implementation to the CodePen above.